# Oracle SQL regexp sum within repeating sequence grouped by

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

First time here, hope someone can help

What's the Oracle SQL select stmt for the XML below stored in an Oracle CLOB field so the following is returned (there will be as many as 96 intvColl blocks per day).

Basically the numeric values in the intvColl blocks between the 2nd and 3rd commas need to be summed and grouped by the date before the first comma and also by the varchar after the 3rd comma.

I'm guessing regexp_substr / but can't quite get there.
The first record is the sum of the 1st and 2nd intvColl blocks
The second record is the sum of the 3rd intvColl block
The third record is the sum of the 4th and 5th

```
MeterChannelID           Date         Sum     Quality   Count_of_records
6103044759-40011200-Q1   14/03/2016   1,387   A         2   
6103044759-40011200-Q1   14/03/2016     694   S         1 
6103044759-40011200-Q1   15/03/2016   1,433   A         2  

<uploadRegData>
    <intervalDataBlock>
        <setDateTime>16/03/2016-19:30:01</setDateTime>
        <intervalMinute>15</intervalMinute>
        <meterChannelID>6103044759-40011200-Q1</meterChannelID>
        <intvColl><intvData>14/03/2016,1,700,A</intvData></intvColl>
        <intvColl><intvData>14/03/2016,2,687,A</intvData></intvColl>
        <intvColl><intvData>14/03/2016,3,694,S</intvData></intvColl>
        <intvColl><intvData>15/03/2016,4,724,A</intvData></intvColl>
        <intvColl><intvData>15/03/2016,5,709,A</intvData></intvColl>
    </intervalDataBlock>
</uploadRegData>
```

Comment: Please add some more details to make your question clearer; besides, what have you tried so far and what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Hi Elgood, welcome to SO. Your question is not very clear. You should take time to help people understand what you want. Here it is not clear at all your expecting your solution to sum some component of the XML. And you also must show you did your own research and show the effort to solve it yourself. Here it rather look like a "do my homework" question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MeterChannelID,
       "Date",
       SUM( value ) AS "Sum",
       Quality,
       COUNT(1) AS Count_of_Records
FROM   (
  SELECT MeterChannelID,
         TO_DATE( SUBSTR( data, 1, 10 ), 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) AS "Date",
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(
                      data,
                      INSTR( data, ',', 1, 2 ),
                      LENGTH( data ) - INSTR( data, ',', 1, 2 ) - 2
                  ) ) AS value,
         SUBSTR( data, -1 ) AS Quality
  FROM   (
    SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '/uploadRegData/intervalDataBlock/meterChannelId' )
             AS MeterChannelID,
           EXTRACTVALUE( d.COLUMN_VALUE, '/intvData' ) AS data
    FROM   ( SELECT XMLType( column_name ) AS xml FROM table_name ) x,
           TABLE(
             XMLSequence(
               EXTRACT(
                 x.xml,
                 '/uploadRegData/intervalDataBlock/intvCol1/intvData'
               )
             )
           ) d
  )
)
GROUP BY MeterChannelID, "Date", Quality
ORDER BY MeterChannelID, "Date", Quality;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting to grips with it slowly

Comment: I can get this to work on Oracle 12, returns ORA-00904: "X"."XML": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Updated - Forgot the alias from the inner `SELECT XMLType( column_name ) AS xml FROM table_name` query.

Comment: Thanks will progress with it, it is currently returning zero records though. I am using a WITH to return one sample record e.g. 'WITH TABLE_NAME AS ( SELECT xxx  as COLUMN_NAME FROM xxx WHERE xxx) then that gets fed into your verbatim query i.e. I don't need to touch your query at all. Thanks again for your help to date, I'll do what I can and appreciate any further help you can provide :)